# Arc length of Archimedes Spiral $ r = \theta $ from $ 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

The equation of the Archimedes spiral is given by $$r = \theta$$
The formula for calculating the Arc Length is given by $$L = \int^b_a\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta$$

The following is my work on this problem so far:

$$L = \int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{\theta^2+1}d\theta$$
Using Trig substitution
$$\theta = \tan(u)$$
$$ d\theta = \sec^2(u)du$$
$$L = \int^{\tan^-1(2\pi)}_{\tan^-1(0)}\left(\sqrt{\tan^2(u)+1}\right)\sec^2(u)du$$
$$L = \int^{\tan^-1(2\pi)}_{\tan^-1(0)}\left(\sqrt{\sec^2(u)}\right)\sec^2(u)du$$
$$L = \int^{\tan^-1(2\pi)}_{\tan^-1(0)}\sec^3(u)du$$

This is basically where I am stuck, and I am also not sure if I am over complicating this problem or am I on the right track?

Ok so after using the integration by parts for the above integral I arrive at:

$$\left[\frac{\sec(u)\tan(u) + ln |\sec(u)+\tan(u)|}{2}\right]^{\tan^{-1}({2\pi})}_{\tan^{-1}(0)}$$

How to evaluate that without a calculator??

Comment: May I suggest $\theta=\sinh(u)$ instead and then double argument formula ? It could be simpler and faster.

Comment: It is a good suggestion if I knew what you were talking about, I am just a calculus II student and we havent done hyperbolic substitutions :(

Comment: Sorry for that ! You will learn them very soon. When I see $\sqrt{1+x^2}$, my first reaction is always that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done! Use

$$\tan(\arctan(x))=x$$

(per definition) and

$$\sec(\arctan(x))=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

(convince yourself of this by looking at a right-angled triangle for a few seconds) to arrive at the result

$$\pi\sqrt{4\pi^2+1}+\frac12\ln\left(\sqrt{4\pi^2+1}+2\pi\right)$$

There is probably no easy way to approximate that number without a calculator, but if I plugged the numbers correctly into mine it should be about $21.25629$.

Comment: Just a minor correction. Where you put secxtanx it should be 2pi not just pi

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong forgot it's all over 2

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To compute $$I=\int \sec^3(x)\,dx$$ the tangent half-angle substitution seems to be convenient.

$$ t=\tan(\frac x2) \qquad dx=\frac{2\, dt}{1+t^2}\qquad \sec(x)=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$$ make $$I=2\int\frac{ \left(1+t^2\right)^2}{\left(1-t^2\right)^3}\,dt$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition leads to very simple terms.

Comment: I think this solution is also a bit complicated as I dont THINK we've learned half-angle substitution. I was wondering if I decomposed $\int\sec^3(x)dx$ to $\int\sec^2(x)\sec(x)dx$ and integrated by parts maybe?

Comment: @Panthy. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: ok, so my intuition was correct... and this problem is truly a pain! but thanks